# async internal calls from visualforce, any quick examples?

Tags: asynchronous

often async calls are used to callout, but what do async calls look like when an org asynchronously queuries itself, so what do “internal async calls” look like in general, and when done from visualforce? I have a visualforce app that needs to query information from a custom object in the same Org

Update: March 9th, 2019: I think I’m going to try using WSDL-based Async callouts using Continuations pattern in Visualforce. I will update this as I learn more.

Update2: After reading David’s answer, I decided to use Visualforce Remoting.

Comment: Why do you need a call out to perform a query? Could you make your question a little more specific and detail your use case here?

Comment: My visualforce app needs to query potentially many records. I dont necessarily need it done via callout, but I think users would prefer the query to be asynchronous so that the page does not hang. In my case the user has given me soqls that they care to see and they expect my page to show them those query results. I am populating (appending) the page with results from  N querys. To avoid gov limits, for many concurrent users, it seems appropriate to use Continuations. However unlike most Continuation vf examples the endpoint to hit (in my scenario) is a web service in the same org. Doable?

Comment: continuations can go to any external web service, this could be the same org (callouts can call back into the same org, that is how the metadata api works when used by apex for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to perform a callout or use a Continuation to achieve your objective. Just use [JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm#!) to asynchronously perform your queries without impacting users' perception of your page's responsivity.

JavaScript remoting:

- > ... [can return](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_declaring_remote_method.htm) Apex primitives, sObjects, collections, ...
- > [aren’t subject to API limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_limits.htm)
- Can return a response with

  > a maximum size of 15 MB
- > must return within 30 seconds

  but can be configured for up to 120 seconds.

You'd define a method like

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<mySobject__c> getObjects(String someQuery) {
    return [SELECT .... FROM mySobject__c ...];
}
```

then, in Visualforce,

```
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getObjects}',
            someQuery,
            handleResult
        );

    function handleResult(result, event) { ... }
```

Your `handleResult()` function would then need to insert the data into the page however you prefer, perhaps using something like jQuery data tables.

You can call the function more than once, in serial or in parallel, so long as your code is prepared to handle the results and you can stay below the 30 seconds/15 MB limit.

You will still have to obey all relevant governor limits, such as having only [50 query cursors open concurrently per user](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), but you won't have to worry about Visualforce view state size because the data won't be in the view state. (Making a callout does *not* get you out of governor limits, in any case).

Comment: Very helpful. I am accepting David’s answer.